# Insert into ... select with a group by in Oracle results in too many values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am porting a MySQL query to Oracle.

```
INSERT INTO
  "stagedInserts" ("systemId", "timestamp")
SELECT
  :systemId AS "systemId", "d"."time" AS "timestamp"
FROM
  "data" "d"
WHERE
  "d"."systemId" = :systemId
GROUP BY 
  TRUNC("d"."time"/900)
```

The GROUP BY is intended to be the equivalent of `"time" DIV 900` in MySQL, to ensure that we end up with only one timestamp for each 15 minute (900 second) interval.

The above query results in `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

However, if I add the GROUP to the SELECT so we end up with:

```
SELECT
  :systemId AS "systemId", "d"."time" AS "timestamp", TRUNC("d"."time"/900)
```

It results in: `ORA-00913: too many values`.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: This is an example of how mySQL appears to be "broken" to those of us who don't use it!  If your `data` table contains rows for `:systemId` with time values 1,2,3,...899 then which one would mySQL store in `stagedInserts` after grouping by `time/900`?  Whatever the answer is, it is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an aggregate function on d.time:

```
SELECT :systemId AS systemId, MAX(d.time) AS timestamp
                              -----------
FROM   data d
WHERE  d.systemId = :systemId
GROUP BY TRUNC(d.time/900);
```

Or you could do this:

```
SELECT :systemId AS systemId, TRUNC(d.time/900)*900 AS timestamp
                              ---------------------
FROM   data d
WHERE  d.systemId = :systemId
GROUP BY TRUNC(d.time/900);
```

Now you are selecting the value that is used in the GROUP BY clause, and multiplying it by a constant, rather than selecting a completely different value.

NB The results of these 2 queries are not the same, so consider which is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

In first case, you are getting error because, whenever you add `GROUP BY` clause to your query, you should also include the same with columns name, which you missed in your first query.

**Add one more column `Trunc_Column` in your table**,which will store truncated value and change your query something similar to

```
INSERT INTO
  "stagedInserts" ("systemId", "timestamp","Trunc_Column")
SELECT
  :systemId AS "systemId", "d"."time" AS "timestamp",TRUNC("d"."time"/900)
FROM
  "data" "d"
WHERE
  "d"."systemId" = :systemId
GROUP BY 
  TRUNC("d"."time"/900)
```

Above query will resolve `ORA-00913: too many values` error.